# How to cross check one column in a file in another and print the missing values?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file that looks like this. It has  12 columns and 3244343 rows. Lets call this file 1.

```
variant_id  gene_id tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se    pval_nominal_threshold  min_pval_nominal    pval_beta
chr10_100000235_C_T_b38 ENSG00000227232.5   35211   73  74  0.061157    1.69779e-08 0.510322    0.0890939   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-05
chr10_100002628_A_C_b38 ENSG00000227232.5   635545  126 130 0.107438    1.01823e-08 0.405406    0.0696647   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-05
chr1_666028_G_A_b38 ENSG00000227232.5   636475  111 115 0.0950413   2.78462e-08 0.411513    0.0729864   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-0
```

I have another file that looks like this with 7 headers and with 1633293 rows. This is file 2.

```
"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100000235_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100000235" "C" "T" "chr10" 101759992
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 101762385
"chr10_100004827_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100004827" "A" "C" "chr10" 101764584
"chr10_100005358_G_C_b38" "chr10" "100005358" "G" "C" "chr10" 101765115
```

I am only interested in the `variant_id` column. This is the  first column in both files.

How can I compare these two columns and only print those `variant_id` values in the first column that are *not found in the second file*. For the above example, the output should be

```
chr1_666028_G_A_b38
```

because it's found in the first file but not the second.

All the values of the `variant_id` in the second file are also in the first file. But there are extra IDs in the first file not present in the second, which I want to identify.

Comment: The main problem will likely be the file sizes. Is there anything you already tried? Is `awk` mandatory? Which shell do you use?

Comment: I've just started learning awk. I'm not sure where to start as I am a beginner. And I am using bash.

Comment: Is your first field always the same between file 1&2 ? like is `variant_id` always double coted ?

Comment: Thanks for your response and  to answer your question Yes. The values of this column (variant_id) in the second file is always found in the first file (variant_id). However, the second file (variant_id) may not contain all of the values, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a system that supports [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), you can use `grep` with the `-v` flag (show non-matching lines) and `-f` flag (read patterns from file), where the "file" is a command that just prints the first field of your file1. For example:

```
$ grep -vf <(awk '{print $1}' file2) file1
variant_id  gene_id tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se    pval_nominal_threshold  min_pval_nominal    pval_beta
"chr1_666028_G_A_b38"   ENSG00000227232.5   636475  111 115 0.0950413   2.78462e-08 0.411513    0.0729864   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-0
```

If that isn't an option, you can just print the first fields into a file and use that:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' file2 > file2.names
$ grep -vf file2.names file1
variant_id  gene_id tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se    pval_nominal_threshold  min_pval_nominal    pval_beta
"chr1_666028_G_A_b38"   ENSG00000227232.5   636475  111 115 0.0950413   2.78462e-08 0.411513    0.0729864   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-0
```

Alternatively, assuming you have enough RAM to hold all variant IDs from file2 (which you should unless you are working on very old hardware), you can use `awk` to store all the first fields of one file and then check the other file for them:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1]++;next}; !($1 in a)' file2 file1
variant_id  gene_id tss_distance    ma_samples  ma_count    maf pval_nominal    slope   slope_se    pval_nominal_threshold  min_pval_nominal    pval_beta
"chr1_666028_G_A_b38"   ENSG00000227232.5   636475  111 115 0.0950413   2.78462e-08 0.411513    0.0729864   0.0006160191.01823e-08  1.17701e-0
```

Comment: I tried this but the top two didn't work. It just prints out everything I have  in file1. E.g. File 1 has 3244343 lines and the output file also have 3244343 lines. Moreover, the output aren't showing the disparities.

Comment: @HKJ3 what operating system are you using? Have you ever opened the file in Windows? Does the last approach work?

Comment: I am using a terminal. I am writing the command directly onto  the terminal rather in a script.

Comment: @HKJ3 OK, but please answer the questions I asked: what operating system are you using? Have you ever opened the file in Windows? Does the last approach work?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The last approach does the same thing as the first two commands. It prints out the file 1 contents. I am using a macOS v12.2.1. I am not using windows.

Comment: Hmm. And you have never opened either file in windows? In that case, I can only assume that the files aren't exactly as you've shown them. Perhaps the variant ID isn't quoted in one of the two files? Are the files really exactly like that? Are they regular text files?

Comment: OHHHH I've just realised what the problem is. I think with the commands you've given me the ordering matters. However, the first columns in both files might be different  orders. For example a value in file 2 can be position 30 that matches position 100 in column 1 file 1.

Comment: So is there a way I can specify the ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: No, the ordering is irrelevant in all cases here. But if the quoting is different, that is super important. Is the quoting different?

Comment: I'm super sorry for bothering you but I've just realised the  first file has no double quotes. No double quotes in the header or the field values. While the second file has double quotes around the column names and field values.

Answer (score 1):

I would first sort the two files (excluding the header of course). I would then use `awk` or `cut` to select the first column (minus the header) and use `comm` to select the ones from `file1` that are not in `file2`, using process substitution:

```bash
comm -23 <(awk 'NR>1 {print $1;}' file1) <(awk 'NR >1 {print $1;}' file2)
```

You can make a minor simplification by refactoring the command in the process substitution[1] into a script, say `col1-nh` ("first column, no header"):

```bash
#! /bin/bash

file=$1

awk 'NR>1 {print $1;}' $file
```

and the command would then be:

```bash
comm -23 <(col1-nh file1) <(col1-nh file2)
```

Again, this assumes that the bodies of the files are *sorted*. But that is `O(N logN)` and both `col1-nh` and `comm` are `O(N)` where N is the number of lines, so it should be able to deal with files of the size you mention without problems. You should of course measure the time that each suggested solution takes.

---

[1] Although with @terdon's suggestion of using `NR>1` in the `awk` invocation, the `sed` is no longer needed, and one could argue that the command is simple enough as is.

Comment: Why sort first? You're already assuming a system that supports process substitution, so there is no benefit in sorting first, just do it on the fly: `comm -23 <(awk 'NR>1{print $1}' file1 | sort) <(awk 'NR>1{print $1}' file2 | sort)`.

Comment: You are right, but I'd rather incur the sort cost once and not have to worry during subsequent invocations. I am assuming that this is a small part of a larger exploration (e.g. doing the same thing for `file2`). BTW, I'll use your `NR>`` suggestion to get rid of the `sed` - thanks!

Comment: I get an error saying /cm/local/apps/torque/var/spool/mom_priv/jobs/19815748.master.cm.cluster.SC: line 15: col1-nh: command not found

Comment: Did you save the `col1-nh` script somewhere on your `PATH` (e.g. `$HOME/bin`)? Did you make it executable with `chmod +x /path/to/col1-nh`?